# How to loop through a function a set number of times?

Tags: javascript

I have this function that takes the string values of '1' and adds a '0' to it.

The problem is that I want it to go through the function a set number of times. 
i.e. I want it to go 6 times so the number ends up being '1' '0' '1' '0' '1' '0' then using the join function to have them as one single value in an array

```js
alert(stringy());

//write a function that names stringy
function stringy(size) {

  //create and empty array to hold new value
  var num = []
  //push a the string value of 1 into array
  num.push('1')
  //loop through the array and if the variable equals 1 then push a 0
  for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (num[i] == '1') {
      num.push('0')
      //if num has 0 in in it push 1
    } else if (num[i] == '0') {
      num.push('1')
    }
    //numbers return two values in array but does not specify how many goes in.
    return num.join();
  } //incomplete: only shows '1,0' in output one time.
}
```

Comment: `return num.join();` outside the `for` loop. Right now its returning at the end of the first iteration of the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a condition before returning, checking that the array size is equal to what is asked for:

```
if (num.length >= size) {
    return num.join();
}
```

The `>` is a safety to avoid infinite looping when `size` is less than 2. Don't forget to pass a `size` when you call the function.

Note that it is bad practice to add to an array while iterating over it: this can be confusing and the cause of undetected bugs. I seem to understand that you got this as a template in a course or something. If so, forget this way of working.

A better design for such a function is:

```js
function stringy(size){
    return Array.from(Array(size), (_, i) => 1-(i%2)).join('');
}
console.log(stringy(5));
console.log(stringy(6));
```

And, there is even a `String#repeat` function:

```js
function stringy(size){
    return '10'.repeat(size/2+1).substr(0,size);
}
console.log(stringy(5));
console.log(stringy(6));
```

Comment: thank you for your help! I am new to developing so I am still learning between good and bad practices! I am happy that this community can be so helpful to new developers like me

Answer (score 1):

A couple problems:

You're not using the passed `size` in your loop. And you're returning inside the for, which returns after just one iteration.

I think this is closer to what you want;

```
function stringy(size){

    var num=[]
    num.push('1')
    for(i=0; i < size; i++){
        if(num[i]=='1'){
            num.push('0')
        } else if(num[i]=='0'){
        num.push('1')    }
    }
    return num.join();
}
```

You can also simplify things a bit which helps the readability:

```
function stringy(size){
    var num=[1]
    for(i=0; i < size; i++){
        num.push( num[i]==1 ? 0 : 1)
    }
    return num.join();
}
console.log(stringy(6))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function something(size) {
    var iterations = Math.floor(size / 2);
    var result = '';

    for (var index = 0; index < iterations; index++) {
        result += '10';
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Use modulo operator:
 * The modulo operator (%) returns the division remainder.
 * So:
 *      0/2 = 0
 *      1/2 = 1
 *      2/2 = 0
 *      3/2 = 1
 *      4/2 = 0
 * @param size int Array size.
 * @return string Joined array: "1,0,1,0,1,0,..."
 */
function stringy(size) {
    var num = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        num.push((i % 2 === 0) ? 1 : 0);
    }

    return num.join();
}
```